# R How to extract data between 9:30am to 2：30pm everyday on stock price dataset

Tags: r, lubridate

```
head(Morgan)
 X.RIC  Date.L.    Time.L.        Type  Open  High   Low  LastVolume
1  MS.N 20060117 2016-03-25 09:30:00 Intraday 1Min 59.45 59.45 59.45 59.45  63100
2  MS.N 20060117 2016-03-25 09:31:00 Intraday 1Min 59.45 59.45 59.44 59.44  20800
3  MS.N 20060117 2016-03-25 09:32:00 Intraday 1Min 59.45 59.46 59.45 59.45   7400
4  MS.N 20060117 2016-03-25 09:33:00 Intraday 1Min 59.45 59.45 59.38 59.38  12100
5  MS.N 20060117 2016-03-25 09:34:00 Intraday 1Min 59.35 59.35 59.30 59.30   4800
6  MS.N 20060117 2016-03-25 09:35:00 Intraday 1Min 59.29 59.30 59.20 59.20   4800

Morgan$Time.L. <- as.POSIXct(Morgan$Time.L.,format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

I already turn the time to a POSIXct mode, but i cannot build a new sequence to match the two list, because the row of data and time is separately stored. Can you help me to extract everyday's data between 9:30am to 2:30pm to form a new data set. or tag the right data in a new row.

Comment: Given the number of different ways dates and times can be stored, this is a case where you _really_ need to post your data as the results of `dput(Morgan)` (or a representative sample of `Morgan`, if it's big) so we can see what the classes are.

Comment: Please edit your post and make it a minimal reproducible example with dummy data (or `dput(Morgan)` and the expected output.

Comment: The output of dput(Morgan )is so large " 19980L, 3170L, 2707L, 4938L, 400L, 11167L, 3652L, 2781L, 
    10600L, 10408L, 6756L, 800L, 6580L, 10639L, 1284L, 5762L, 
    2301L, 4900L, 15953L, 4101L, 5795L, 9065L, 6800L, 1724L, 
    3123L, 11820L, 1384L, 9627L, 7552L, 4390L, 3201L, 11052L, 
    21811L, 2800L, 2054L, 10166L, 3615L, 1615L, 3819L, "

Comment: What i want to do is to make a time window between 09:30 am and 2:30 pm. Please pay attention that some rows may be missing, so the exact time for someday may not exist in this data. And the Time row's date is wrong, is because i code as.POSIXct(Morgan$Time.L.,format = "%H:%M:%S") so it auto add a random data to every day.

Comment: the original data                                                                                       >>X.RIC  Date.L.         Time.L.          Type  Open  High   Low  Last Volume                 
>>1  MS.N 20060117 09:30:00.000000 Intraday 1Min 59.45 59.45 59.45 59.45  63100

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly clear to me what you need as output, but my assumption is that you want to split the data set by dates. If this is the case you could use the `dlply` function from the package `plyr` to split the dataframe into a list of results by date.

Typing something like: `dlply(.data = Morgan, .variables = "Date.L.")` should return a list of data frames for each date.

Answer (score 0):

Without using other packages, if `Time.L.` is class `POSIXct`, then you can just treat it like you would a number and build a conditional statement:

```
lower <- as.POSIXct(strptime("09:30:00", format = "%H:%M:%S"))
upper <- as.POSIXct(strptime("14:30:00", format = "%H:%M:%S"))
subset(Morgan, subset = Time.L. >= lower & Time.L. <= upper)
```

Comment: Thank you--if you feel this solves the question completely, please accept it as an answer so that others may find it more easily.